# How to capitalize a string?

Tags: string, google-bigquery

I need to capitalize a string:

john doe -> John Doe

How to do this?

I suppose need to use NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD, but it returns a lower case.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#normalize_and_casefold

NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD

NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD(value[, normalization_mode])
Description

Takes a STRING, value, and performs the same actions as NORMALIZE, as well as casefolding for case-insensitive operations.

NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD supports four optional normalization modes:

Value   Name    Description
NFC Normalization Form Canonical Composition    Decomposes and recomposes characters by canonical equivalence.
NFKC    Normalization Form Compatibility Composition    Decomposes characters by compatibility, then recomposes them by canonical equivalence.
NFD Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition  Decomposes characters by canonical equivalence, and multiple combining characters are arranged in a specific order.
NFKD    Normalization Form Compatibility Decomposition  Decomposes characters by compatibility, and multiple combining characters are arranged in a specific order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and with use of JS UDF (first query) and SQL UDF (second one)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION capitalize(str STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return str.replace(
      /\\w\\S*/g,
      function(txt) {
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
      }
  );
""";
SELECT str, capitalize(str) capitalized_str
FROM `project.dataste.table`
```

or

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION capitalize(str STRING) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(word, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(word, 2))), ' ' ORDER BY pos)
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str, ' ')) word WITH OFFSET pos
));
SELECT str, capitalize(str) capitalized_str
FROM `project.dataste.table`
```

you can test above with dummy data as

```
WITH `project.dataste.table` AS (
  SELECT 'john doe' AS str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc xyz'
)
```

with result for both options:

```
Row str         capitalized_str  
1   john doe    John Doe     
2   abc xyz     Abc Xyz
```

> Added least verbose / more streamlined version for JS UDF

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION capitalize(str STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return str.replace(/\\b(.)/g, function(match, chr){return chr.toUpperCase();});
""";
SELECT str, capitalize(str) capitalized_str
FROM `project.dataste.table`
```

Comment: It works. I see it would be better to begin to store Javascript functions as a library in Google Storage, then need to execute this query from bq command line tool - how it is done? Also, I have BW Mate installed - does it calculate the cost of the Javascript function?

Comment: see [Including external libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries). it is not exacly what you asked but at least can save some typing :o)

Comment: [BQ Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) provide estimated cost based on BigQuery Engine's estimated bytes to be processed. UDF does not contribute into extra dollar-cost but rather contribute into performance and resource consumption and applies some [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) to query it is in

Comment: only this limit is relevant, but it is reasonable :The amount of data that your JavaScript UDF outputs when processing a single row — approximately 5 MB or less.

Comment: exactly! please vote, accept if it helped and addressed your question :o)

Answer (score 3):

There is big query function for that INITCAP - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#initcap

```sql
select INITCAP('john doe');
```

Returns `John Doe`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is a little bit more complex than the easier way...

CONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTR( field,1,1 ) ), SUBSTR( Bets.status_code,2,CHAR_LENGTH(field) ) ) as CapitalizedField