# How do I capitalize a string appropriately?

Tags: python

I've been instructed to capitalize a string provided by the user, e.g.:

“what time do i have to be there? what’s the address?” >>
“What time do I have to be there? What’s the address?”

Additional instructions are: "You must write the functions below from scratch. Do not rely on any other built-in or pre-existing functions
that appear to provide any of this functionality for you."

I've consulted articles such as the following but I have trouble understanding the accepted answer due to my lack of knowledge of programming language. 
[How to capitalize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812000/how-to-capitalize-a-string)

Also, this example only asks to capitalize the first letter in each of two words, so it doesn't cover capitalization following a "?" or "."

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest a regex? This regex matches any char preceded by the text start or a punctuation (question mark, period or exclamation mark). Then you replace any matched char with the uppercase like this: `re.sub(r"(?<=(^|\?|\.|\!)\s*)\w", lambda x: x[0].upper(), "text to capitalize! put it here!")`

Comment: Have you tried anything else? Maybe some code to how are you approaching the problem.

Comment: Just found that python doesn't support variable length lookbehind and I cant edit the comment so here is what actually works: `re.sub(r"(^|\?|\.|\!)\s*(\w)", lambda x: x[0].upper(), "text to capitalize! put it here!")`

Answer (score 0):

Built it from scratch. Try this out:

```
s = input()
s = list(s)
if ord(s[0]) >=97 and ord(s[0]) <=122: #if the first character is small
    s[0] = chr(ord(s[0]) - 32) 
for i in range(0, len(s) - 2):
    if s[i] == '?' or s[i] == '!' or s[i] == '.':
        if (ord(s[i + 1]) >=97 and ord(s[i + 1]) <=122):  #assuming no space after ? . !
            s[i+1] = chr(ord(s[i+1]) - 32)
        if (ord(s[i + 2]) >=97 and ord(s[i + 2]) <=122): #assuming there is a space after ? . !
            s[i+2] = chr(ord(s[i+2]) - 32) 

s = ''.join(s)
print(s)
```

The logic is that if the first character or any character after `? . !` is a small letter (which has [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) code between 97-122) we reduce it's [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) code by 32 so as to convert it to a capitalized letter (which has [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) code between 65-90).